# Timer in application_start to switch 'current deal'

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc-3, razor

Been trying to figure out the best method to accomplish this task and I will attempt to explain what I'm thinking as straight forward as possible.

I am working with a website that is similar to woot.com, whiskeymilitia.com etc where there is a deal of the day or of a certain time limit, IE: 15 minute deal. I am trying to create a timer that will run upon application start every x seconds like say every 5 seconds and check whether the deal time limit has elapsed.

I'm currently querying the database to give me the active deal that should be displaying but I'm not entirely sure how I would implement this inside of Application_Start. Basically it would check the deal and the deal limit time + elapsed time and determine whether or not to flag that deal as inactive at that point. Is it possible to route a model I query in application start to a controller?

Any kind of advice would be excellent as this is a new concept to me here and would love to come up with a solid solution!

Feel free to have me clarify anything if needed! Thanks again :)

-- EDIT --

After looking into SqlDependency I ran into an error upon testing everything out.

The SQL Server Service Broker for the current database is not enabled, and as a result query notifications are not supported.  Please enable the Service Broker for this database if you wish to use notifications.
Your host has to enable SQL Service Broker on your database. Most shared environment hosting companies seem to avoid doing this, stating that it's meant more for a dedicated server environment.

Searching for an alternative. Figured I would drop this off for people to peak at before running into the same thing.

-- EDIT 8:30PM --

So I have tried to utilize the Cache class to accomplis this issue but I'm just completely stuck.

```
    public ActionResult Index()
    {            

        CurrentDealModel model = new CurrentDealModel();

        model.DealQueueDetails = db.FirstOrDefault<ProductQueue>("SELECT * FROM ProductQueue WHERE Active = 1");

        model.ProductDetails = db.FirstOrDefault<Product>("WHERE Id = @0", model.DealQueueDetails.ProductId);

        return View(model);
    }
```

I would like to cache this data in the controller for the amount of time stored in the variable model.DealQueueDetails.DealTimeLimit - The problem with this solution is that the administrator will determine how long a deal will display for which means I need to cache based on that value. If there is anyone that could lend some extra help I would be super grateful!

Per James Johnson and others I have tried

Cache.Insert("AbsoluteCacheKey", cacheData, null, 
    DateTime.Now.AddMinutes(15), System.Web.Caching.Cache.NoSlidingExpiration

However setting cacheData to my model is returning a NullReferenceException. Sigh why must I struggle so much on this hehe.

Answer (score 1):

ASP.NET is not the right place to implement any kind of timing functionality. Use either a scheduled task or a service, or store an expiration date in one of the server-side storage mediums (Cache, Application, etc.) and check it on every request.

I would suggest Cache with a SqlDependency: [SqlDependency in an ASP.NET Application](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/9dz445ks.aspx)

**EDIT**

If using a `SqlDependency` is off the table, just set an absolute expiration:

```
Cache.Insert("AbsoluteCacheKey", cacheData, null, 
    DateTime.Now.AddMinutes(15), System.Web.Caching.Cache.NoSlidingExpiration);
```

Comment: I would love to do this but I have searched quite a bit to get some light shed in a proper direction but I'm having a difficult time coming up with how it would all work. I have a database that is storing the time that I am pulling from, I was just wanting to implement a Sleep thread until the time had elapsed and then it would just refresh the page.

Comment: Use `Cache` with a SqlDependency.

Comment: Like save the page state in Cache for the amount of time and then release it or something like that?

Comment: There are a couple of ways to handle it. You could set an explicit expiration, or you could set it to expire when some data in SQL changes. Either way, the Cache object is what you're looking for.

Comment: I really like the solution of Cache and SqlDependency but as I said this is such a weak subject for me and understanding how the global.asax works and if I even need to do this in application_start or what so I guess it's off to research more. Thanks

Comment: I would create a a base class for all your pages to inherit from, and use that instead of the global.asax file.

Comment: Geez, that just went above my head hehe

Comment: Heh, I just don't see the need in all that. There has to be a better way.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/11058/discussion-between-jhartzell-and-james-johnson)

Comment: This is a lot easier, and a lot more reliable than using a timer, and given your requirements I don't think there is a better way. These features were designed for situations just like yours.

Comment: @jhartzell: Since using a SQL Dependency is off the table, just set an absolute expiration.

Answer (score 0):

I recommend you to keep the current deal in a Cache, so that you don't have to hit the database. But, then, how will it be updated when necesasry? Well, simple answer: set the expiration of the cache at the absolute time when the deal finishes, so that it has to go to the databse to find the new deal.

Pseudocode:

```
  public Deal GetDeal()
  {
      if (Cache contains deal)
          return deal from cache;
      else
      {
          get deal
          add deal to cache with absolute expiration
      }   
  }
```

To use the cache, look at this:

- [Cache Class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.caching.cache.aspx)
- [Cache.Add Method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.caching.cache.add.aspx) (use absoluteExpiration parameter)
- [Cache.Get Method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.caching.cache.get.aspx)

With this implementation you don't have to worry about performance, polling, server restarts, dependencies, or whatever else.

Comment: I have revised my initial question and just added edits to remove some of the unnecessary comments and additional question.

Answer (score 0):

Alright so after 12 hours of tinkering and researching I was finally able to get this implemented correctly and it is working so well It makes me want to start worrying for it lol.

```
    public ActionResult Index()
    {

        ViewBag.Message = "Welcome to ASP.NET MVC!";

        CurrentDealModel model = new CurrentDealModel();

        model.DealQueueDetails = db.FirstOrDefault<ProductQueue>("SELECT * FROM ProductQueue WHERE Active = 1");

        model.ProductDetails = db.FirstOrDefault<Product>("WHERE Id = @0", model.DealQueueDetails.ProductId);
        var DealTime = model.DealQueueDetails.DealTimeLimit;
        var CurrentTime = System.DateTime.Now;

        TimeSpan span = DealTime.Subtract(CurrentTime);

        var model1 = HttpContext.Cache.Get(model.DealQueueDetails.Id.ToString());
        if (model1 == null)
        {
            model1 = HttpContext.Cache.Add(model.DealQueueDetails.Id.ToString(), model, null, System.DateTime.Now.Add(span).AddSeconds(10), Cache.NoSlidingExpiration, CacheItemPriority.High, new CacheItemRemovedCallback(RedirectToNewDeal));
            var CachedObject = HttpContext.Cache.Get(model.DealQueueDetails.Id.ToString());
            return View(CachedObject);
        }
        return View(model1);

    }
```

Minus some variables that need to be renamed and some re factoring on this it is working perfectly. I then have a CacheItemRemovedCallback set to the below function.

```
    public static void RedirectToNewDeal(String key, Object item, CacheItemRemovedReason reason) 
    {
        DatabaseEntitiesDB db = DatabaseEntitiesDB.GetInstance();

        if(reason.ToString() == "Expired")
        {
            var QueueToDisable = db.FirstOrDefault<ProductQueue>("WHERE Id = @0", key);
            QueueToDisable.Active = false;
            QueueToDisable.Update();
        }
    }
```

Also some refactoring needing to be done to this as well for some error handling/logging however this has worked out just as I had expected. Now the only thing other than this is that I'm having to invoke a AJAX Polling method inside the main few every 3 seconds to check the cache and I'm doing that like so.

```
     public ActionResult CacheCheck(string key)
    {
        var GetCachedObject = HttpContext.Cache.Get(key);

        if (GetCachedObject != null)
        {
            return Content("NotExpired");
        }
        return Content("Expired");

    }
```

AJAX Call

```
setTimeout(function () {
        setInterval(CacheCheck, 2000);
        CacheCheck();
    }, 10000);

function CacheCheck() {
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: '@Url.Action("cachecheck", "home", new { key = Model.DealQueueDetails.Id })',
            success: function (data) {                    
                if (data == "Expired") {
                    window.location.reload();
                } 
            }
        })
    }
```

If anyone knows of a better way to refresh the page and pull in the new deal I am all ears!

Thanks for everyone and their help and I hope this helps other people as well!